# Promise.all problem in making pwa for website

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make a pwa of my website for the first time but i have a problem

its my code

```
let expectedCacheNames = Object.values(CURRENT_CACHE);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.forEach(cacheName => {
                    if(!expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) > -1){
                        return caches.delete(cacheName)
                    }
                })
            )
        })
    )
```

and i get this error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything (-> `undefined`). But what's the use case for `.forEach()` anyway in this case?

Comment: please show more code, what is your cacheNames? I think "cacheNames" is your problem, not the Promise.all

Comment: If `.delete()` is [`Cache.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete) then you want either `.reduce()` or `.filter()`+`.map()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its working

```
return Promise.all(cacheNames).then((values) => {
                values.forEach(cacheName => {
                    if(!expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) > -1){
                        return caches.delete(cacheName)
                    }
                })
            });
```

Comment: What is "working"? This answer doesn't make any sense. And `.forEach()` still doesn't return anything.